# Render from all my dynamic SelectField in my FieldList are overwritten by the first one

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms, fieldlist

In my project, I want to create several pair of Select field to make a composition of different materials (on selection among all the label of the material, and one selection among 0.1 and 20 %).
This is my forms :

```
class MatForm(Form):
    mat = SelectField()

class List_Compose_Form(Form):
    list_mat = FieldList(FormField(MatForm))
    submit=SubmitField('Select Composition')
```

So I create a function to create a list of Mat form with default value for all the key like ('Batch(MAT)' or 'MAT (%)') and all the associated possible choices (list of possible labels or a range between 0.1 and 20 :

def compose_form(grades):

```
raw_name = 'interface_app\grades_raw\\'+str(grades)+'_clnd.raw'
[dic_compose,dic_choice] = pickle.load(open(raw_name,'rb'))
all_mat_items = []
for key, values in dic_compose.items():
    mat_id = uuid.uuid1()
    mat_entry = MatForm(request.form)
    mat_entry.mat.label = key
    mat_entry.id = mat_id
    if re.search('%',str(key)) :
        choice = [(values,values)]
        choice += [(str(i/10),str(i/10)) for i in range(1,200)]
    else: 
        choice = [(values, values)]
        choice += [(dic_choice[key][i],dic_choice[key][i]) for i in range(1,len(dic_choice[key]))]
    mat_entry.mat.choices = choice
    all_mat_items.append(mat_entry)
return(all_mat_items)
```

This part is actually working and I can indeed create my composition:
[composition page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJVav.png)

This is the app where I create the list and I save the data in the session

```
@app.route("/compose",methods=['GET','POST']) 
@grade_required
def compose():
   the_grade=session['grade']
   session['dic_compos'] = {}
   form =List_Compose_Form(request.form)
   list_mat = compose_form(the_grade) 
   form.list_mat = list_mat
   if form.submit.data and form.validate():
       for k in form.list_mat :
           k.validate()
           session['dic_compos'].update({k.mat.label : k.mat.data})
       return redirect(url_for('test'))
   return render_template('compose.html',form=form)
```

But for some unknown reason the data that I get from each field is overwritten by the first like :
[session dictionary after composition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZVlI.png)

For me this issue is probably linked to MatForm(request.form) in my loop of composition or probably to my jinja2 template :

```
<div class="table-responsive-sm">
  <form action="" method="post" role="form">
    <table id="data" class="table table-dark table-responsive overflow-auto" style="height:400px">
      <thead >
        <tr>
          <th>Labels</th>
          <th>Selected</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for mat_form in form.list_mat %}
          <tr>
            <th>{{mat_form.mat.label}}</th>
            <th>{{mat_form.mat}}</th> 
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </form>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
      {{ form.submit }}
    </div>
  </form>
```

And I tried to add csrf token or to used render_field from ([_formhelpers.html](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/) )with different name to avoid overwriting but nothing works.
I'm working one this issue since 2 days, so every help is welcomed.

Tell me if you need additional precision/explanation this is my first ASK.

Comment: It's more likely that you get an answer if you 1) post the error traceback as text insted of image, 2) try to isolate the exact problem you are having

Comment: ok , I don't get special error, all my page are working and i can make my composition and fill each field, the problem is, when I print the dictionnary of the composition for the session, I get the same value for all my material. It means that all my k.mat.data  in my loop are overwritten by the selected data of my first select field, independently of what I have selected in the other